# Javasctipt call object's function from array

Tags: javascript, canvas

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <canvas id ="mainCanvas" width = "400" height = "400"></canvas>
    <script src ="script.js"></script>
    <script src ="test.js"></script>

</body>
```

**test.js**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas")
var context = canvas.getContext("2d")

var array = [
    context.fillRect
]

array[0](10,10,10,10)
```

It says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Normally this `context.fillRect(10,10,10,10)` works...

So Why can't i call that reference from array?

Comment: why do you need to store that same function in array multiple time ?

Comment: Just testing functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is actually context. When you type array[0] you are in the context of that function object (a function is an object in javascript). But you want to be in context of context variable. So there are two solutions

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas")
var context = canvas.getContext("2d")

var array = [
function(params) {
context.fillRect(params)
}
]

array[0](10,10,10,10)
```

or second method using `call`

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas")
var context = canvas.getContext("2d")

var array = [
context.fillRect
]

array[0].call(context,10,10,10,10)
```

Comment: Wow thanks ;)
How is it i cant invoke that without that function(params) Cuz its invoking objects'function?